# ImportError: cannot import name PunktWordTokenizer

Tags: python, nltk, importerror

I was trying to use PunktWordTokenizer and it was occurred an error as below.

```
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktWordTokenizer
```

And this gave the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "file", line 5, in <module>
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktWordTokenizer ImportError: cannot import name PunktWordTokenizer
```

I've checked that nltk is installed and that PunkWordTokenzer is also installed using nltk.download(). Need some help for this.

Comment: What is your nltk version? `import nltk; print nltk.__version__`

Comment: Also, did you happen to name your file `tokenize.py` or `nltk.py`?

Comment: NLTK version is 3.2.2

Comment: Is it still a problem after `pip install -U nltk`?

Comment: When I tried to execute this command, an error was occurred.                   >>> pip install -U nltk
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install -U nltk
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/installing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a regression related to PunktWordTokenizer in 3.0.2. The issue was not present in 3.0.1, rolling back to that version or earlier fixes the issue.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.__version__
'3.0.2'
>>> from nltk.tokenize import PunktWordTokenizer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name PunktWordTokenizer
```

For solving this Try `pip install -U nltk` to upgrade your NLTK version.

Comment: mine `nltk` version is 3.4 and i am still unable to import `PunktWordTokenizer`

Answer (score 4):

PunktWordTokenizer was previously exposed to user but not any more. You can rather use WordPunctTokenizer.

```
from nltk.tokenize import WordPunctTokenizer
WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(“text to tokenize”)
```

The difference is :

PunktWordTokenizer splits on punctuation, but keeps it with the word. Where as WordPunctTokenizer splits all punctuations into separate tokens.

For example, given Input: **This’s a test**

```
PunktWordTokenizer: [‘This’, “‘s”, ‘a’, ‘test’]
WordPunctTokenizer: [‘This’, “‘”, ‘s’, ‘a’, ‘test’]
```