# Error in importing 'punkwordtokenizer' from nltk.tokenize using nltk==3.4

Tags: python, nltk, importerror

as i have the same question but didn't get the proper solution for solving my problem. I search out on this problem but no solution results in removal of error. i found the following error while executing the simple code :
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
" File "cook1.py", line 23, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize import PunktWordTokenizer
ImportError: cannot import name 'PunktWordTokenizer' from 'nltk.tokenize' "
```

I am using the python 3.7.3 and nltk==3.4 
same question has been answered already but i didn't find the results after these mentioned solutions.
Please if anyone can help. Thanks

Comment: So is it punk or punkt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name PunktWordTokenizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238864/importerror-cannot-import-name-punktwordtokenizer)

Comment: it is punkt @Norrius

Comment: yeah this is the same question but i didn't get my problem solution from there mentioned solution

Comment: But did you see the answer about PunktWordTokenizer no longer being exposed to user and to use WordPunctTokenizer instead?

Comment: no i didn't get your point clearly

Comment: Sorry, maybe using “exposed” isn’t clear. To put it a bit simply, in earlier versions you could import it. Now you can’t. But you can import WordPunktTokenizer, so use that.

Comment: oh ok thank you i get your point . i try it

Comment: maybe more explicitly, do this: `from nltk import wordpunct_tokenize`